# What happened to 13 Hours: The Secret Soldiers Of Benghazi?

Tags: distribution, 13-hours

Maybe I missed something on television, but how is **13 Hours: The Secret Soldiers Of Benghazi** not out on DVD yet?

I saw this movie in theatre and have not seen a commercial for its DVD release date, and I just typed it into Google and can only find an [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4172430/) reference.

Deadpool came out way after this movie and is already out for DVD.

Why hasn't this movie been released yet?

Comment: Popular thought is that everything about this movie is timed to be politically perfect to affect the US elections, from the initial theatrical releases (just prior to the Iowa caucuses) to the pay cable/DVD release being schedule just prior to the US general presidential elections...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [locating or purchasing Movies or TV content is off-topic](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: How on earth can it be closed for that? He isn't asking where to purchase a DVD, or where to stream it.... he's asking why it has not yet been released _on DVD yet_, which considering the amount of time since theatrical release is a _valid question_... If you Google/Bing search you'll see many others have asked the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

First off, just because Movie A is out on DVD doesn't mean Movie B (released the same day) will necessarily be out on DVD as well. Particularly if Movie A's gross was 10 times that of movie B, or Movie A was marketed to a worldwide audience, while movie B's was marketed only to a single political niche in one country.

That being said, 13 Hours *does* appear to be available on Blu-ray right now, at least from [Red Box](http://www.redbox.com/movies/13-hours-the-secret-soldiers-of-benghazi). If what I am seeing at [Blu-ray.com](http://www.blu-ray.com/movies/13-Hours-The-Secret-Soldiers-of-Benghazi-Blu-ray/152491/) is correct, its available retail at Best Buy, but Walmart and Target both have "exclusives" on it right now. If you want the version that comes with a free camo shirt, it looks like Walmart is your place.

Comment: I'm sorry, the correct answer was "It's an illuminati conspiracy!".

Answer (score 1):

Everyone is reporting that it's due for release on [June 7, 2016](http://www.movieinsider.com/m12477/thirteen-hours/releases).  You can pre-order it from several sites, such as Amazon, Target and Wal-Mart.